# Can you multiply one element of a NumPy array and get the entire array as a result?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a multidimensional NumPy array, and I want to multiply the first element of each sub-array by some number. If I create an array and use slice notation to just get the elements I want to multiply, it returns just those elements in a new array, not the rest of the elements in the original array. How can I multiply the first elements and keep them in the original array?

Example: I do this

```
>>> arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> arr
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> arr[:,0] * 5
```

and I get this

```
array([ 5, 20])
```

but I would like to get this

```
array([[ 5, 2, 3],
       [20, 5, 6]])
```

Comment: Have you tried a real cross product? Like `arr * np.array([5,1,1])` ?

Comment: @cowbert your original tuple was fine arr * (5,1,1) array([[ 5,  2,  3],
       [20,  5,  6]])

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reassign the results:

```
In [8]: arr[:, 0] = arr[:, 0] * 5

In [9]: arr
Out[9]: 
array([[ 5,  2,  3],
       [20,  5,  6]])
```

Comment: Same thing but different: `np.multiply(arr[:,0], 5, out=arr[:,0])`.

Comment: @wwii Yes, more abstraction more distance from the Truth.

Comment: Yep ... assignment to the slice is easier to understand when read.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
arr = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
arr[:,0]*=5
```

The good old **multiply AND** assignment operator